# How to plot two functions together using odeplot?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, maple

I'm trying to compare (graphically) approximations obtained using Euler's method and RK4-method.

```
ode := {diff(y(x), x) = 2*cos(x)*y(x), y(0) = 1};    
p := dsolve(ode, y(x), numeric, method = classical[rk4], stepsize = .25);     
f := dsolve(ode, y(x), numeric, method = classical[foreuler], stepsize = .25)
```

But can't plot them together.

```
plots:-odeplot([p, f], x = 0 .. 10);

Error, (in plots/odeplot) input is not a valid dsolve/numeric solution
```

How can I solve this problem? Besides, I want to use style=point for "euler" curve,  and plot exact solution on the same graph, if it's possible. What is the best method to obtain exact solution?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: this seems to be more of a programming issue than a math one. Obviously it's applied to math in a programming language that's very much geared towards math, but I don't know how the community feels about debugging code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key to answering you question is that you can produce the plots separately (using `odeplot` or `plot`), and then combine them together using the `plots:-display` command.

For fun, let's plot the two numeric methods with `style=point`, at the x-values that match the fixed step-size of the forward-Euler method.

I find it more convenient to use `plot` instead of `plots:-odeplot` here, after using the `output=listprocedure` option of `dsolve` (numeric).

```
restart;

ode := {diff(y(x), x) = 2*cos(x)*y(x), y(0) = 1}:

stpsz := .25;

                     stpsz := 0.25

a,b := 0, 10;

                     a, b := 0, 10

numpts := floor((b-a)/stpsz + 1);

                      numpts := 41

p := dsolve(ode, y(x), numeric, method = classical[rk4],
            stepsize = stpsz, output=listprocedure):

f := dsolve(ode, y(x), numeric, method = classical[foreuler],
            stepsize = stpsz, output=listprocedure):

e := dsolve(ode, y(x)):

Pe := plot(eval(y(x),e), x = a..b, style=line, legend="Exact"):

Pp := plot(eval(y(x),p), a..b, color=blue,
           style=point, symbol=circle, symbolsize=10,
           adaptive=false, numpoints=numpts, legend="RK4"):

Pf := plot(eval(y(x),f), a..b, color=green,
           style=point, symbol=diagonalcross, symbolsize=10,
           adaptive=false, numpoints=numpts, legend="For.Euler"):

plots:-display(Pe, Pp, Pf);
```

[image]

You can issue the commands `eval(y(x),e)` and `eval(y(x),f)` separately, to see that they are a syntax for picking off the RHS expression or procedure from the `dsolve` solution.

Comment: Thank you very much, it was the best possible answer. Now it's clear for me how to plot graphs of approximations. :)